# Rails 5 production app intermittently spikes with nodejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, performance

I have a Rails 5 app, and on the production server, sometimes a user will go to the site and the browser just spins and spins.  Whenever this happens, we ssh into the box, and run top, and we see that nodejs is hogging the CPU.  This occurs after the box has been running just fine for a while, i.e. it's not the first time a user has accessed the site after a deploy.  I am mentioning this last piece because one hypothesis we had was, perhaps the first time a user hits a view, some assets are being compiled (even though we don't have that-view-specific-assets).   Here's the output of top when this happens:

```
3707 deploy    20   0  998724 119820  14060 R  68.4  3.0   0:02.95 nodejs                                                                                                                                     
3702 deploy    20   0 1023804 152868  14020 R  66.8  3.8   0:03.70 nodejs                                                                                                                                     
3712 deploy    20   0  958788  77108  13800 R  17.6  1.9   0:00.53 nodejs
```

Does anyone know why nodejs spikes like this during regular production access to a Rails application (by "regular," I mean, not an exceptional access, such as the first time after a deploy).

Thanks,
Kevin

UPDATE - posting config/environments/production.rb

Rails.application.configure do
    # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests.
config.cache_classes = true

# Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
# your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
# and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
# Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
config.eager_load = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
# Apache or NGINX already handles this.
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = true

# `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
# config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

# Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

# Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
# config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
# config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
# config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
# config.force_ssl = true

# Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
# when problems arise.
config.log_level = :debug

# Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

# Use a different cache store in production.
# config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

# Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
# config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
# config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "opencaseware_#{Rails.env}"
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
# the MAIL_HOST will have to be set as an environment variable every server
# that is running this code if they want to send out emails
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['MAIL_HOST'] }

# Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
# Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
# config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
# the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
config.i18n.fallbacks = true

# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

# Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

# Use a different logger for distributed setups.
# require 'syslog/logger'
# config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail

if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
  logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
  logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
  config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
end

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendgrid_actionmailer
config.action_mailer.sendgrid_actionmailer_settings = {
    api_key: nil
}
```

end

Comment: Post your production env. config file.

Comment: @bkunzi01 updated question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the fallback specified by:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

I did a writeup here explaining the solution:

http://uptime.mainstreetcomputing.com/intermittent-spikes-production-nodejs-rails-application/